# how can i have over 30 users to use my ubuntu with ssh?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh

I am trying to implement a network system. That students can connect to it by the ssh command or Putty.
In the main computer I have ubuntu os. I want an admin to add a new students each time and give them exact amount of space.
The students can connect to the main computer through the wifi.
my purpose is:
Students can work with the Terminal of ubuntu even if they don't have this os on their own systems.
and I want one of these users to be the admin so that it can delet the old users and add new ones.
I have no idea where to begin so if you guys could just give me a hits that means a lot.

Comment: there is something called quota, to allot space. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/
you also might do well to make all your users in a sub directory of your admin user, esp certain admins have certain sets of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is a multi-user OS, so there is no problem with allowing others to access.

To be able to use putty or connect from MacOS terminal students will need ssh client (included in all linux distributions as a standard and MacOS iirc as a `ssh` binary, or Windows ssh client, like Putty).

Now, on your server you will need ssh server, install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If you use ufw - unblosk ssh traffic to your machine:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Now just add users, for example by running:

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/[username] -m [username]
```

Create Password for user:

```
sudo passwd [username]
```

Now, that is pretty basic setup, but your students are able to log in to their own accounts and work in shell.

To limit amount of space users can use, use quota application, but it's configuration might be slightly complicated at first glance (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-user-and-group-quotas).

Read also about ssh server configuration, as there are some options like allowing root user to log in that you might want to change (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring).

For user to have administrator privileges, use sudo (see, for example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

Remember, that your students machines need to be on the same network for them to be able to connect to your computer (in this, simplest example).